# Can I add an additional method to a WebElement

Tags: java, selenium

I'm using Java Selenium Page Factory methodology.

I use the @FindBy notations in my page factory:

```
@FindBy(id = "randomButton")
public WebElement randomButton;
```

Because I have so many buttons on any given page I abstracted out a generic button click method so that I didn't have to re-write so much code:

Before:

```
public void randomButtonClick(WebElement pageElement) throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(randomButton));
    randomButton.click();
}
public void button2Click(WebElement pageElement) throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(button2));
    button2.click();
}
public void button3Click(WebElement pageElement) throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(button3));
    button3.click();
}
and so on for the other 10-20 buttons on any given page
```

After:
I then added a generic action class and then just passed in all the buttons:

```
public void click(WebElement element){
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
    element.click();
}
```

In my calling test I was calling it like:

```
myPage.randomButtonClick();
```

but now I call it like:

```
genericAction.click(myPage.randomButton);
```

Is there a better way to do this?  I feel like the flow of my test cases now has this semi-unreadable code.  Doing it this way did save me hundreds of lines of code but now the readability is down.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If you just eliminated hundreds of lines of code your readability is now *up*, not down. If that's too complicated for someone reading your code then they shouldn't be reading your code.

Comment: Is this method signature correct randomButtonClick(WebElement pageElement)? Because when u r calling u r not passing any arguments

Comment: Also, can you add the code for 2 more buttons how it was in your before code ? Just for more clarity ?

Comment: @javaguy just added a few more so  you can get a feel for it.  I literally had 20-30 of those per page. The site has many buttons.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a multitude of possibilities here rendering answers be based on opinions. You should consider reviewing your question to avoid a TIMTOWTDI-like discussion, if any.

To your question, `randomButtonClick()` was definitely inaccurate as it implies clicking a RANDOM button rather than the one you provide. Although, based on your code, you do not provide any with that method (?).

On the other hand `genericAction.click(myPage.randomButton);` also includes a random button. But more importantly, you are trying to beat a dead horse here by creating a `genericAction` (I assume it's a `class GenericAction`). This solution is not a bad one, it's a duplicate. Check out `org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions` for example. It's readable and allows you to chain your interaction events.

Lastly, keep in mind the solutions you get will not necessarily always fit your webpage/application. If you are confident the level of abstraction you achieved with your `genericAction` is good and you are able to handle all buttons with it, go for it.

PS. Still not sure about the `random` word. Are you actually trying to click a random button?